# Make SQLITE Trigger work with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

How do I make this sqlite trigger compatible with MYSQL, I have never used triggers with MYSQL and I'm confused.

```
             CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS update_this AFTER INSERT ON this
             BEGIN
             UPDATE `another` SET `something` = `something` + new.number;
             END;
```

Solution  :

```
     delimiter |
     CREATE TRIGGER update_this AFTER INSERT ON this`
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     UPDATE `another` SET `something` = `something` + NEW.something WHERE `id`= NEW.id;
     END;
     |    
     delimiter ;
```

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 1):

Unverified:

```
delimiter //
    CREATE TRIGGER update_this AFTER INSERT ON your_table
    BEGIN
        UPDATE `another` SET `something` = `something` + new.number;
    END;
//
```

Comment: I played around with it and found a solution, thanks everyone for trying